# Convert Multiple audio tracks into a Single Track with 12 channels using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have multiple MOV files and each file has different numbers of audio tracks. I want to convert those files to MOV and combine the audio into a single 12-channel audio track.

For example, I have a source file with 4 single-channel audio tracks, and that file has to be output to a file with a single 12-channel audio track. The 1st audio track from the source file must be output to the 1st channel; the 2nd track to the 2nd channel; the 3rd track to the 3rd channel; the 4th track to the 4th channel; and channels 5–12 in the output file will be left without audio.

Another example: If the source file has 6 single-channel audio tracks, then these 6 tracks will be mapped to channels 1-6 channels in the output file and channels 7-12 will be left without audio.

Below is my FFmpeg command.  It completes the video transcode without issue and also outputs a single 12-channel audio track. The problem is that all the audio tracks from the source file are being combined in the 1st channel, and channels 2-12 have no audio. I'm using Switch Telestream Player to QC the files.

```
ffmpeg -i <input>.mp4 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 0 -quant_mat 2 -c:a pcm_s16le -b:a 512K -filter_complex "[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c1[a1];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c2[a2];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c3[a3];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c4[a4];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c5[a5];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c6[a6];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c7[a7];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c8[a8];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c9[a9];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c10[a10];[0:a]pan=mono|c0=c11[a11];[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8][a9][a10][a11]amerge=inputs=12[aout]" -map 0:v -map "[aout]" <out>.mov
```

I'm using [FFAStrans](https://ffastrans.com/wp/) and its included `ffmpeg` executable to automate the movement and transcode of every file that has been placed in its watchfolder. Can you help me build the correct `ffmpeg` command?

Comment: I would include a linked minimal source file for testing purposes and also edit the question to include the output of your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, I'm thinking of a way on how to share the sample files I have. I didn't notice that sooner that the source files I was testing is a MOV file and not Mp4.

Comment: this is the sample file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DzPl5oa5ZHz-_TKhbnndzKcAuH1gulat/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [Did this](https://superuser.com/a/1784454/) solve your problem?

Comment: Hello, I apologize for not updating you sooner. Thank you for sharing and explaining the command in detail. Yes, the command work as expected. However, the command must be executed in an Ffastrans, with that the command must be static. This command work if the source file has 4 single-channel audio tracks, and if the files has more than 4 single-channel audio tracks the ffastrans will fail.

Comment: It give the idea to combine the ffmpeg with a powershell script and execute in the ffastrans, and it works. Now even the Ffastrans will pick up source files with single channel tracks audio layout it will then transcode them on an expected audio layout. However, there is another problem: there were files with multiple channels within tracks that needed to be outputted as a single 12 channel audio track, and the powerlshell command failed it.

Comment: My goal was to identify the original issue, which wasn't related to Ffastrans, but to actual code.  This was specific to 4 tracks, and if a different number of tracks the command would need to be adapted.  Generating a script that will properly build the command now that the syntax is better understood (Fftrans or otherwise) seems to be a problem in and unto itself that may benefit from a new question.

Comment: Hello, yes it already solve the specific issue. thank you for your assistance and for devoting some of your time to assisting me in resolving the issue and explaining the ffmpeg command in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula below I included only the code related to mapping the mono tracks into a 12-channel track.

```
ffmpeg -i test_file.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0];[0:a:1]pan=mono|c0=c0[a1];[0:a:2]pan=mono|c0=c0[a2];[0:a:3]pan=mono|c0=c0[a3];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a4];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a5];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a6];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a7];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a8];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a9];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a10];[0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a11];[a0][a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8][a9][a10][a11]amerge=inputs=12[aout]" -map 0:v -map "[aout]" -c:a pcm_s24le -c:v copy output_file.mov
```

In your original code, only `[a0]` contains sound after mixing.  You weren't, as you thought, mixing/combining the four mono tracks/channels into the same `c0` of the 12-channel track.  `[a1]`-`[a11]` were mixed from mono channels that didn't exist (anything other than `c0`) and that's why the channels they were mapped to were silent. It was hard to pick up on this initially because your test file contains 4 identical mono tracks, so one can't distinguish by ear if mono tracks were being mixed together or simply lost.

The issue with your code is shown in the tables below that compare the original with the new.  Note that using `[0:a]` for audio track 0 is interpreted by `FFmpeg` as equivalent to `[0:a:0]`

#### Original Code

| Command | Input Track | Input Channel | Input Audio Note | Mapped Sound? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0] | [0:a:0] | c0 | Mono track 0 - c0 has audio | c0: Yes |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c1[a1] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c1: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c2[a2] | [0:a:0] | c2 | Mono track 0 - c2 isn't valid | c2: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c3[a3] | [0:a:0] | c3 | Mono track 0 - c3 isn't valid | c3: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c4[a4] | [0:a:0] | c4 | Mono track 0 - c4 isn't valid | c4: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c5[a5] | [0:a:0] | c5 | Mono track 0 - c5 isn't valid | c5: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c6[a6] | [0:a:0] | c6 | Mono track 0 - c6 isn't valid | c6: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c7[a7] | [0:a:0] | c7 | Mono track 0 - c7 isn't valid | c7: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c8[a8] | [0:a:0] | c8 | Mono track 0 - c8 isn't valid | c8: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c9[a9] | [0:a:0] | c9 | Mono track 0 - c9 isn't valid | c9: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c10[a10] | [0:a:0] | c10 | Mono track 0 - c10 isn't valid | c10: |
| [0:a]pan=mono|c0=c11[a11] | [0:a:0] | c11 | Mono track 0 - c11 isn't valid | c11: |

#### New Code

| Command | Input Track | Input Channel | Input Audio Note | Mapped Sound? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c0[a0] | [0:a:0] | c0 | Mono track 0 - c0 has audio | c0: Yes |
| [0:a:1]pan=mono|c0=c0[a1] | [0:a:1] | c0 | Mono track 1 - c0 has audio | c1: Yes |
| [0:a:2]pan=mono|c0=c0[a2] | [0:a:2] | c0 | Mono track 2 - c0 has audio | c2: Yes |
| [0:a:3]pan=mono|c0=c0[a3] | [0:a:3] | c0 | Mono track 3 - c0 has audio | c3: Yes |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a4] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c4: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a5] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c5: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a6] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c6: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a7] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c7: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a8] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c8: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a9] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c9: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a10] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c10: |
| [0:a:0]pan=mono|c0=c1[a11] | [0:a:0] | c1 | Mono track 0 - c1 isn't valid | c11: |

Answer (score 0):

I did some bash script, but I dont know how it helps you

```
#!/bin/bash
f="input 4.mp4"
if [ ! -f "$f" ]; then
ffmpeg -lavfi "
testsrc[v];
aevalsrc=sin(440*2*PI*t):s=8000[a];
aevalsrc=sin(880*2*PI*t)|sin(1760*2*PI*t):s=16000[b];
" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -map "[b]" -t 5 "$f" -hide_banner -y
fi

AUD=($(ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams a -show_entries stream=channels -of csv=p=0 "$f"))
MRG=""
CNT=0
INP=0
for a in ${AUD[@]}; do
  echo "channels=$a"
  MRG+="[0:a:${CNT}]"
  ((CNT+=$a))
  ((INP++))
done
SIL=""
while (( $CNT < 12 )); do
  SIL+="aevalsrc=0[a${CNT}];"
  MRG+="[a${CNT}]"
  ((CNT++))
  ((INP++))
done

ffmpeg -i "$f" -filter_complex "
${SIL}
${MRG}amerge=inputs=${INP}[a]
" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le /tmp/out.mov -hide_banner -y

ffplay -f lavfi "amovie='/tmp/out.mov',asplit[a][out0];[a]showspectrum=s=540x1080:mode=separate:legend=1[out1]" -hide_banner -autoexit
```